# Adding (Nolock) to all select statements in long running SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services

We have over 500 SSRS reports, is there a way to add all missing (nolock) in the select statements of each dataset by writing a TSQL script?  Thanks.

Comment: Are *all* 500 of the reports you have slow running reports? Why not start with the slowest, and go from there? The miracle you seek doesn't exist.

Comment: I assume you have investigated and optimised the queries as far as reasonably possible.... If you are not worried about getting the up to the seconds live data (maybe your data is updated infrequently) then you could make the job simpler by add
`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` at the top of the query. It's not the most elegant solution  but for me, when the data I am reporting on is only updated overnight, it speeds things up considerably.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks R. and Alan!

Comment: Yes,  Alan's comment above is correct.  Our DBA's would endorse it.  One *other* way to speed up queries is to do an "inner" query just to find the relevant database id's (usually specific table-column or columns) that satisfy the relevant conditions, then do the rest of the query in an outer query. While this idea seems simple it can literally speed up certain queries by a factor of 1000 or more!  People take note in stand-up!